# how to move existing documents from one collection to another within the same database/forest in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Can someone please suggest some way to move existing documents from one collection (or the default one) to another within the same database/forest in MarkLogic.

Comment: “Move” is not really what happens when you change a collection. Think of a collection as a tag on a document. (Unlike directories, collections are related many-to-many with documents.) A collection only exists if at least one document declares it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function [`xdmp:document-set-collections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-set-collections) to set the collections a document is in without reinserting it. If you just want to make specific changes, [`xdmp:document-add-collections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-add-collections) and [`xdmp:document-remove-collections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-remove-collections) can be used to add or remove some collections without modifying the rest.

Like Tyler said, you'll want to batch it up or use corb if there are a lot of documents you want to process.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to Re-insert the documents at the same uri but add the new/different collection.

You'll want to query the documents using something like [`cts:search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) and then do a [`xdmp:document-insert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert), the 4th parameter is where you put the collection(s).

If it's a lot of do documents you'll want to batch this up in sizes from 10 to 1,000 depending on the size of the documents, if you aren't sure 100 is a good starting place.

If this is a really big amount use corb2.